# How can I input an Icon in Navbar of IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I have just added some actions in my Navbar. Some of the actions are appearing with the Icon of question mark. How can I add some different Icons so as not to get confused.

For example one of the action is Tools->Deployment->Upload to...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Settings | Menu and Toolbars | Your_Toolbar` (or RMB on the `toolbar | Customize Toolbar)`
2. Select an action with an icon | Edit | Choose custom icon
3. Click on 'OK'

Comment: Thanks for posting! Unfortunately, your answer did not address one specific aspect of the question. The OP is asking about adding an icon for an action that doesn't have one.